# Possible to set inline <li> all to the same height?

Tags: html, css

I have different content for each `li` what would be the best way to make sure that they are the same height, no matter what content is within them [[JS fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqsmwkc/)?

Example:

The first quote is shorter than the second quote, how would the `li` container keep the same height for both, but not be a set variable?

> Sed elementum porta auctor. Proin ut mi ac enim cursus mollis. Ut
>   scelerisque, lorem vitae semper finibus, ipsum diam convallis mauris,
>   eget tincidunt ipsum elit et mauris.

-

> Donec tempor augue tellus, malesuada scelerisque metus mattis et.
>   Nullam lacinia convallis commodo. Curabitur aliquet lobortis eros.
>   Aenean condimentum dolor ut magna consequat porta.

```css
/*-- wrappers --*/
div.wrapper {
        min - height: 200 px;
        height: auto;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: auto auto;
        padding - top: 35 px;
}
/*-- content containers --*/
ul.col {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: auto auto;
    list - style - type: none;
}
ul.col > li {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline - block;
    padding: 10 px;
}
ul.col > li.ct {
    text - align: center;
}
ul.col > li.br {
    border: solid 1 px# CCC;
    border - radius: 5 px;
}
ul.col > li > div.img - container {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding - bottom: 10 px;
    text - align: center;
}
ul.col > li > div.img - container.mh128 {
    min - height: 128 px;
}
ul.col > li > div.img - container.mh128 > img {
    display: inline - block;
    padding - top: 32 px;
}
ul.col > li > div.img - container > img {
    border - radius: 5 px;
}
ul.col > li > div.img - container > img.w100 {
    width: 100 % ;
}

ul.col > li > h1 {
    padding - bottom: 5 px;
    font - family: 'bl-light'
    sans - serif;
    font - size: 14 px;
}@
media screen and(min - width: 500 px) {
        /*-- navigation --*/
        div.nav > ul {
                width: 975 px;
            }
            /*-- headers --*/
        div.header > h1,
            div.header > p {
                width: 975 px;
            }
            /*-- wrappers --*/
        div.wrapper {
                width: 975 px;
            }
            /*-- content containers --*/
        ul.col > li.col - 3 {
                width: calc(100 % / 3 - 20px);
                    float: left;
                }
                ul.col > li.col - 3. br {
                    width: calc(100 % / 3 - 22px);
                        }
                        /*-- footers --*/
                    div.footer > ul {
                        width: 975 px;
                    }
                }

                @
                media screen and(max - width: 975 px) {
                    /*-- navigation --*/
                    div.nav > ul {
                            width: 500 px;
                        }
                        /*-- headers --*/
                    div.header > h1,
                        div.header > p {
                            width: 500 px;
                        }
                    div.header.sm {
                        padding: 10 px 0;
                    }
                    div.header.sm > h1 {
                        font - family: 'bl-light'
                        sans - serif;
                        font - size: 24 px;
                    }
                    div.header.sm > h1.solo {
                        line - height: 50 px;
                        text - align: center;
                    }
                    div.header.md {
                        padding: 20 px 0;
                    }
                    div.header.md > h1 {
                        font - family: 'bl-light'
                        sans - serif;
                        font - size: 48 px;
                    }
                    div.header.md > h1.solo {
                        line - height: 100 px;
                        text - align: center;
                    }
                    div.header.lg {
                        padding: 30 px 0;
                    }
                    div.header.lg > h1 {
                        font - family: 'bl-light'
                        sans - serif;
                        font - size: 60 px;
                    }
                    div.header.lg > h1.solo {
                            line - height: 150 px;
                            text - align: center;
                        }
                        /*-- wrappers --*/
                    div.wrapper {
                            width: 500 px;
                        }
                        /*-- content containers --*/
                    ul.col > li.col - 3 {
                        width: calc(100 % -20 px);
                        display: block;
                    }
                    ul.col > li.col - 3. br {
                            width: calc(100 % -22 px);
                        }
                        /*-- footers --*/
                    div.footer > ul {
                        width: 500 px;
                    }
                }

                @
                media screen and(max - width: 500 px) {
                    /*-- navigation --*/
                    div.nav > ul {
                        width: 100 % ;
                    }
                    div.nav > ul li.collapse {
                        display: inline - block;
                    }
                    div.nav > ul ul.collapse {
                        display: none;
                        border - top: solid 1 px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
                    }
                    div.nav > ul ul.collapse.pull - right {
                        float: none;
                    }
                    div.nav > ul > ul.collapse > li {
                            display: block;
                        }
                        /*-- headers --*/
                    div.header > h1,
                        div.header > p {
                            width: 100 % ;
                            word - break: break -all;
                        }
                        /*-- wrappers --*/
                    div.wrapper {
                            width: 100 % ;
                        }
                        /*-- content containers --*/
                    ul.col > li.br {
                            border - left: none;
                            border - right: none;
                        }
                        /*-- footers --*/
                    div.footer > ul {
                        width: 100 % ;
                    }
                }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul class="col">
      <li class="col-3">
         <div class="img-container mh128">
            <img src="./assets/icon-sports.png" />
         </div>
         <h1>
            Praesent vel iaculis elit.
         </h1>
         <p>
            Sed laoreet nibh ac est facilisis, quis porta augue dignissim. Sed sit amet aliquet magna, nec commodo velit. Nam sit amet sollicitudin purus, at rutrum nisi. Nulla faucibus ligula sit amet massa ultrices ultricies lobortis lobortis justo.
         </p>
         <a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">Find Out More</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-3">
         <div class="img-container mh128">
            <img src="./assets/icon-about.png" />
         </div>
         <h1>
            Nunc in ipsum vel ligula laoreet scelerisque. 
         </h1>
         <p>
            Donec tempor augue tellus, malesuada scelerisque metus mattis et. Nullam lacinia convallis commodo. Curabitur aliquet lobortis eros. Aenean condimentum dolor ut magna consequat porta.
         </p>
         <a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">Keep Reading</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-3">
         <div class="img-container mh128">
            <img class="nr" src="./assets/icon-contact.png" />
         </div>
         <h1>
            Maecenas nec rutrum nibh.
         </h1>
         <p>
            Sed elementum porta auctor. Proin ut mi ac enim cursus mollis. Ut scelerisque, lorem vitae semper finibus, ipsum diam convallis mauris, eget tincidunt ipsum elit et mauris.
         </p>
         <a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">Read More</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

*Note: my website is going to be responsive, that's why there are media tags and such*

Comment: Perhaps consider `line-height` on the li elements, or the text contained within. I managed to use that to get consistent height on a topbar menu I was working on, so it may solve your problem.

Comment: You can use `ul{display:table}` and `li{display:table-cell}` - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqsmwkc/1/)

Comment: Did you try to use `min-height`?

Comment: @AlexChar - what if the content becomes bigger than min-height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery:

This will find the biggest height size on the li´s and will reproduce the same height too all li´s.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var heights = $("ul.col li").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $("ul.col li").height(maxHeight);
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqsmwkc/2/)**